# How do I tweak my code to export a set range instead of a selection to CSV

Tags: vba, excel, csv

The following code works to export a selected range of cells:

```
Sub saveSelection2csv()

Dim dataRow As Range
Dim dataRowArr() As Variant



    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test.csv" For Output As #1

    For Each dataRow In Selection.Rows.Rows
        dataRowArr = dataRow.Value
        dataRowArr = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(dataRowArr))
        Print #1, Join(dataRowArr, ",")
    Next

    Close #1

End Sub
```

How can I change this code to export a static range? i.e. Sheet1.Range("A1:D100")

Comment: replace `Selection.Rows.Rows` with `Sheet1.Range("A1:D100").Rows.Rows`

Comment: Did you *try* toying with `Sheet1.Range("A1:D100")` instead of using `Selection`?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub saveSelection2csv()

Dim dataRow As Range
Dim dataRowArr() As Variant

    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test.csv" For Output As #1

    For Each dataRow In Sheet1.Range("A1:D100").Rows 'just fix here
        dataRowArr = dataRow.Value
        dataRowArr = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(dataRowArr))
        Print #1, Join(dataRowArr, ",")
    Next

    Close #1

End Sub
```